# Added data is only showed after restarting Internet Explorer

Tags: php, mysql, internet-explorer, browser-cache

I've made a php-program with some simple MySQL database-activity. This all works fine in Chrome and Firefox but in Internet Explorer (IE) there's something annoying about it. When adding and retrieving I can see all the added data in Chrome and Firefox but in IE it doesn't show up. When I close and restart IE again the last added data is shown. It looks to me a cache (flush?) problem and therefore added the following cleach-cache code:

```
<?php
header("Expires: Tue, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
?>
```

But this doesn't work. I'm using Internet Explorer 11 and hopefully somebody can help me the fix this annoying problem

Comment: I found it out by myself. It turns out te be a AJAX-problem and adding a random-value solve the problem. Okay it's a little bit of a hack but it works.
For more information: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/ajax-cache-problem-in-ie/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your site failed to specify a freshness lifetime for the cached resource, forcing IE to use heuristics; see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250442(v=vs.85).aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/07/14/caching-improvements-in-internet-explorer-9.aspx

Your cache headers WOULD work if you specified them properly. You should **not** send **Pragma** nor **pre-check** or **post-check**.

Your headers should be as follows:

```
Expires: Tue, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0
```

This will prevent IE from reusing the cached response in anything other than back/forward navigation (which, by-design, ignores the server's cache-directives).